# Proxy decrypting and serving remote encrypted resources

Tags: nginx, proxy, http, encryption

Imagine the following scenario:

1. Host A serves via HTTP `hello_world.jpg`, which has been AES-encrypted.
2. Host B, which acts as a proxy being aware of Host A's resources, responds to a HTTP call by fetching and decrypting `hello_world.jpg`.

Is there any easy way to do this with an existing proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many proxy servers can call an external helper program to process and modify any content that is requested using the proxy. Others will also/instead support custom lua scripts to perform request modifications.

Squid for instance has the [`url_rewrite_program`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/url_rewrite_program/) directive.  See this implementation for example: https://www.funkypenguin.co.nz/how-to/april-fools-pranks-with-a-squid-proxy-server/

LUA support in:

- Ngnix https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module
- Apache httpd https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_lua.html

Comment: Thanks @HBrujin. In addition to what you are pointing to, I stumbled upon this library and example that might do the trick: https://github.com/c64bob/lua-resty-aes